# iTextsharp PDF Generation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create PDF in a .NET application.  I do not need to save/write the PDF to a server for storage.  Just create a file to the users local machine.  Posted controller below.  Not sure where I am going wrong.  'Return path' is throwing an error :

> "Error    CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult'"

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileResult DailyReport(string path ="")
    {
        path = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) ? path : String.Format("~/downloads/daily-report.pdf");
        var report = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(report, new FileStream(MapPath(path), FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        report.Open();

        var table = new Table(2, 1) { Width = 100, Border = 0, Cellpadding = 2 };

        table.AddCell(
               new Cell(new Paragraph("Daily Schedule", new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD)))
               {
                   Border = 0,
                   HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                   Colspan = 2
               });
        table.AddCell(new Cell { Colspan = 2, Border = 0, Leading = 2 });

        report.Add(table);
        report.Close();

        return path;
    }
    public static string MapPath(string path)
    {
        return (path.StartsWith("~") ? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path) : path);
    }
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Since you didn't tell us what problem you're having, nor did you ask a question, we aren't sure where you're going wrong either.  Are you getting an error?  What is it doing, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: @Amy Updated question.  Getting "Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult'""

Answer (score 2):

Your method is declared to return a `FileResult` instance

```
public FileResult DailyReport(string path ="")
```

but you return a `string`

```
return path;
```

and .Net has no idea how to make that `string` a `FileResult`. Thus,

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult'

You should simply return a `FileResult` instance instead, e.g.

```
return new FilePathResult(path, "application/pdf");
```